# curl no response echo print

Tags: php, json, curl

I was wondering why im not gettting any response. I already uncommented the curl in php.ini in my php in xampp. (I found other post that i should also uncomment curl part of php.ini in apache and php4 folder but there was only 1 php.ini, which is found in php dir).

Also before i uncommented the curl part, the browser would give an unrecognized function error. After i uncommented it, it was okay, so i guess its okay in this part.

```
<?php

$whmusername = "my_email";
$whmpassword = "my_password";

$query = "https://api.appannie.com/v1/accounts";

$ch = curl_init();
// Sets the URL cURL will open
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $query);
// Here's the HTTP auth
// The 3rd argument is your Twitter username and password joined with a colon
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $whmusername." : ".$whmpassword);
// Makes curl_exec() return server response
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
// And here's the result JSON
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

echo 'Code line went here 1,';

print $response;
echo $response;

echo 'Code line successful here too';
?>
```

Then all i get in my browser is:
    Code line went here 1,  Code line successful here too

No response? Or am i forgetting something.
I want to be able to see the response or the json format?

Here is the link to thier api:
http://support.appannie.com/entries/23224038-1-Quick-Start
http://support.appannie.com/categories/20082753-Analytics-API

Also. i got this code from here:
[Appannie api basic authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16575242/appannie-api-basic-authentication)

Can someone else try these please?

Comment: Script is right.{"code": 401, "error": "Unauthorized access"}{"code": 401, "error": "Unauthorized access"} my response

Comment: How did you see the response? 
any changes? Why do you think i get no response at all?

I only get:

Comment: No.Just copied your script in file and runned by php file.php in terminal.Do you have enabled error_reporting ?or check logs for errors

Comment: check `if ($response === false) { die(curl_error($ch)); }` for one. never assume that curl succeeded. then do stuff like `var_dump($response)` to see what's really in there. remember that browsers will LIE to you about what you've received, if they think it's html to be rendered.

Comment: I think so. If not, how? Please... Im currently looking at the php.ini file and searched error_reporting. DOnt know which to uncomment though.

Comment: ini_set('display_errors',1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors',1);
error_reporting(-1);// place at the top of script

Comment: Placed it. still . I could not see the response unlike what you saw.. tried it on both chrome and firefox, the same. but using the    if ($response === false) , i could somehow get the idea that it really failed.