# How can I convert terminal cURL to PHP cURL?

Tags: php, json, curl

I am using curl in the terminal to access and request a JSON file. It should respond with a JSON file.

```
curl --basic --user email : password "http:/www.appannie.com/v1/accounts/acntnum/..."
```

What is its equivalent in PHP curl?

I have used:

```
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $email.".".$password);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    $info = curl_getinfo($ch);
    $httpCode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE); 
    curl_close($ch);
     
    return $response;
```

But it fails.

My reference is this:
http://support.appannie.com/categories/20082753-Analytics-API

Answer (score 1):

I believe the USER PASSWORD needs to be separated by ':'

```
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $email.":".$password);
```

Comment: Somehow i cant see the exact error. But when i used var_dump($response), It will print bool(false). That's why i think the curl failed. I dont why my browser dont show the error.

Comment: I have another link to my question which i created earlier than this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17710671/curl-no-response-echo-print